# Global plan breaks in the middle

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-melodic, navfn

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using navigation forked from tag [1.16.3](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/tree/1.16.3).

I specified a goal in a large room and tried to create a global plan.
The global plan does not extend from the goal to the robot's position, and the robot gets stuck.

The distance between the goal and the robot is roughly 50 meters. At about 10 meters, the global plan is created and the robot proceeds towards the goal. ( The distance is a sensory value and may be off by a large margin. )

Therefore, we believe that there is a limit to the distance of the global plan.

What should I do to extend the global plan to the robot?

##### Environment

- Linux distribution : Ubuntu 18.04 ROS
- distribution : melodic

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/371846/global-plan-breaks-in-the-middle./) by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1908 on 2021-02-15

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know if this is the best way, but I rewrote

```
pathStep = 0.5;
```

to

```
pathStep = 1.0;
```

in `navfn/src/navfn.cpp`, and now the global plan is created even at roughly 50 meters.
The global plan is probably coarser as a backlash, but I don't feel it when I look at it with rviz, and it seems to be working fine now.

---

Originally posted by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) with karma: 1908 on 2021-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) on 2021-03-25**:
It's been a while since I asked the question, but I didn't get any other answers, so I'll call this a solution.
If I get additional good answers, I will change the best answer, so please let me know if there is a better way.